# How to run a Shiny docker container on Alpine Linux?

Tags: docker, shiny, alpine-linux

I have Alpine Linux 2.6 64-bit installed with the latest version of docker. I pulled the rocker/shiny container to test Shiny. All is well but when I try to run the temporary container via:

```
docker run --rm -p 3838:3838 rocker/shiny
```

I get nothing. I verified the container exists via `docker images`. What am I missing?

Comment: Improvement: You can’t check that a container exists with `docker images` because that command shows you which machine images you have `docker pull`‘ed. `docket ps -a` should show you containers.

Comment: To try: try removing all unnecessary parameters, and `docker run -it rocker/shiny bin/sh`. If you can’t connect to the shell then your container has never started.

Answer (score 0):

Your container might be running in the background, you can use

```
docker ps
```

If you start the container with 
`--name shiny`, you can give the running container a name. If you'd want to "log in" to the container you could start a shell inside of it by running something like:

```
docker exec -ti shiny /bin/sh
```

If you want to log into a running container which is not named explicitly you can also check out the name of your container by checking the output of

```
docker ps
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not running in the background because the process is not listed with docker ps.

Comment: I’m don’t think alpine Linux is bundled with bash. Would probably be `/bin/sh`

Comment: Ah, that might be right. Assumed it was, but I stand corrected.